# Why did Windows 10 automatically open 1 Word document, but not 2 others, from the same folder?

Tags: boot

Call the 3 Word documents 1.docx, 2.docx, 3.docx. They're  in the same folder. I followed [Allen Wyatt's instructions for "Opening a Word Document when Starting the Computer"](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008301_Opening_a_Word_Document_when_Starting_the_Computer.html) that is [encapsulated by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd). Then 1.docx automatically opened on startup, perfectly. But 2.docx and 3.docx failed to open automatically.

Only after I renamed 2.docx and 3.docx (to Two.docx, Three.docx) did Windows open these renamed Word documents automatically after startup. Why?